# Running cleaning/validation code before committing in sqlalchemy

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm totally new to PostGreSQL and SQLAlchemy, and I'm trying to figure out how to run validation/cleaning code on an SQLAlchemy model before it is committed to the database.  The idea is to ensure data consistency beyond the standard type enforcement that comes built into SQL databases.  For example, if I have a `User` model built on SQLAlchemy's models,

```
class User(db.Model):
   ...
   email = db.Column(db.String())
   zipCode = db.Column(db.String())
   lat = db.Column(db.Float())
   lng = db.Column(db.Float())
   ...
```

Before committing this document, I want to:

- trim any leading & trailing spaces off the email field
- ensure that the zip code is a 5-digit string of numbers (I'll define a regex for this)
- automatically look up the corresponding latitude/longitude of the zip code and save those in the `lat` & `lng` fields.
- other things that a database schema can't enforce

Does SQLAlchemy provide an easy way to provide Python code that is guaranteed to run before committing to do arbitrary tasks like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the easiest is to hook onto the update and insert events. http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/events.html

```
from sqlalchemy import event

def my_before_insert_listener(mapper, connection, target):
    target.email=target.email.trim()
    #All the other stuff

# associate the listener function with User,
# to execute during the "before_insert" hook
event.listen(
    User, 'before_insert', my_before_insert_listener)
```

You can create custom sqlalchemy types that do this sort of thing.

Comment: can you elaborate on how I can "create custom sqlalchemy types" to do that sort of thing?

Comment: Not sure of the specifics of the specific of what you want to do I am going to have to refer you to the documentation. http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/custom_types.html .The most common pattern is to override the process_bind_param and process_result_value of a existing sqlalchemy type.